# Allow users to create their own page/s

Tags: posts, customization, pages, users

I Create a network where any register user have a profile, from user profile i want enable user to create own page/s where he can post like Facebook. There is a way to do this with wordpress or i must create it ad hoc? I have see wordpress Multisite can it a solution?

Comment: Have you had a look at BuddyPress?

Comment: i just use buddypress for profile user but i haven't find any function to allow user create own page